# Activity vs Fragment Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on new application where I am using `Activity` and `Fragment`. Any main difference between them ??

### Update

I found good answer which I wanted in Android docs.

Docs described

> The most significant difference in lifecycle between an activity and a fragment is how one is stored in its respective back stack. An activity is placed into a back stack of activities that's managed by the system when it's stopped, by default (so that the user can navigate back to it with the Back button, as discussed in Tasks and Back Stack). However, a fragment is placed into a back stack managed by the host activity only when you explicitly request that the instance be saved by calling addToBackStack() during a transaction that removes the fragment.

Does host `Activity` keep different back stack of different `Fragment` associated with it and any scenario where your single application keep multiple stacks. ??

Comment: -1 Not by me, Activity doesnt depend on Fragment's Life Cycle, but Fragment depends on Activity's Life Cycle.

Comment: Well.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Yes, Its not a bad question. But its kind of discussion quest and you can find difference on google or developer site it self.

Comment: [link for fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) and [link for activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) I hope you will be able to find out the difference by yourself...not a bad question though no downvote from me. But first you should go through the material and ask the specific question.

Comment: Seriously you didnt find the difference ?

Comment: Ok, I trust you, may be you didnt search it properly. Because lots of blogs and sites mentioned these differences.

Answer (score 51):

```
 Differences between Activity and Fragment lifecyle in Android
```

Fragment is a part of an activity, which contributes its own UI to that activity. Fragment can be thought like a sub activity.
Fragments are used to efficiently use the space in wider screen devices.

An activity may contain 0 or multiple number of fragments based on the screen size. A fragment can be reused in multiple activities, so it acts like a reusable component in activities.

A fragment can't exist independently. It should be always part of an activity. Where as activity can exist with out any fragment in it.

A fragment lifecycle is more complex than the activity lifecycle because it has more states. Lifecycle states are shown below:

[image]

**onInflate**

At very beginning of the fragment life the method onInflate is called. In this method we can save some configuration parameter and some attributes define in the XML layout file.

**onAttach**

After this step onAttach is called. This method is called as soon as the fragment is “attached” to the “father” activity and we can this method to store the reference about the activity.

**onCreate**

It is one of the most important step, our fragment is in the creation process. This method can be used to start some thread to retrieve data information, maybe from a remote server. The **onCreateView** is the method called when the fragment has to create its view hierarchy.During this method we will inflate our layout inside the fragment.

During this phase we can’t be sure that our activity is still created so we can’t count on it for some operation. We get notified when the “father” activity is created and ready in the **onActivityCreated**.

**From now on, our activity is active and created and we can use it when we need.**

**onStart**

The next step is **onStart** method. Here we do the common things as in the activity onStart, during this phase our fragment is visible but it isn’t still interacting with the user.

**onResume**

When the fragment is ready to interact with user **onResume** is called.

Then it can happen that the activity is paused and so the activity’s **onPause** is called. Well **onPause** fragment method is called too.

After it, it can happen that the OS decides to destroy our fragment view and so **onDestroyView** is called. After it, if the system decides to dismiss our fragment it calls **onDestroy** method.

Here we should release all the connection active and so on because our fragment is close to die. Even if it is during the destroy phase it is still attached to the father activity. The last step is detach the fragment from the activity and it happens when **onDetach** is called.

I hope you can understand from this.

Thanks.

Comment: I see you have explained the each method of fragment life-cycle , OP simply asked you the main difference between the `Fragment` and `Activity` life-cycle not the complete description like what is `Fragment` and their callback description. You should read the question again, so go and read it

Comment: You missed `onStop`.

Comment: @Malwinder, yes, in https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-lifecycle-multiple-screen-support.html onStop is also forgotten :)

Answer (score 11):

*Directly from developer Fragments guide* -

The lifecycle of the activity in which the fragment lives directly affects the lifecycle of the fragment, such that each lifecycle callback for the activity results in a similar callback for each fragment.

For example, when the activity receives `onPause()`, each fragment in the activity receives `onPause()`.

Fragments have a few extra lifecycle callbacks, however, that handle unique interaction with the activity in order to perform actions such as build and destroy the fragment's UI. These additional callback methods are:

**1)** *onAttach()* =>

> Called when the fragment has been associated with the activity (the
>   Activity is passed in here).

**2)** *onCreateView()* =>

> Called to create the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.

**3)** *onActivityCreated()* =>

> Called when the activity's onCreate() method has returned.

**4)** *onDestroyView()* =>

> Called when the view hierarchy associated with the fragment is being
>   removed.

**5)** *onDetach()* =>

> Called when the fragment is being disassociated from the activity.

Once the `activity` reaches the resumed state, you can freely add and remove `fragments` to the `activity`. Thus, only while the activity is in the resumed state can the lifecycle of a fragment change independently.

However, when the `activity` leaves the resumed state, the `fragment` again is pushed through its lifecycle by the `activity`.

Check [Activity and Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: @TGMCians - This is directly from docs. Nothing modified. See the line `Fragments have a few extra lifecycle callbacks`. That is mentioned nothing new. Yes you can say that it doesn't cover the complete differences.

Answer (score 0):

Its similar in one sense. Both gets its life cycle till they exist on the screen. If your activity is closed, it is stopped and destroyed later. Similarly Fragments gets destroyed if they are no more available in the scree. But since fragments live inside a activity, its likely that fragments are destroyed whenever some other fragment replaces this fragment. Thus it owns a similar but distinct lifecycle.