# Android setText Causes Force Close

Tags: android, settext

I'm developing Android app with fragment. If I add setText in MainActivity.java inside onCreateView method, I will get Force Close error when running the app.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.app02;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    t.setText("weewoufzklfo");

}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
                    PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

                    //set the text of textView
        TextView txvMain = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        txvMain.setText("afsewtrwe");

                    //set a drawable as the background of the textView

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.app02.MainActivity" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
    -->
    <!--
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container.
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.app02.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.app02.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to add setText method correctly?

Comment: Have you tried printing `t` to see if it's null?

Comment: Showing the error from the logcat output in the question would help.

Comment: Yup. logcat will help tremendously.

Comment: For the luva Mike, can you show the error you are getting???

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your fragment layout's `textView` `R.id.result` in the `onCreate()` of your activity, which at that point might not even exist. Try setting the value of your `textView` in the fragment class itself.

```
public class YourFragmentClass extends Fragment
{

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        textView =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result);
        textView.setText("weewoufzklfo");
        return view;
    }
}
```

Take a look at fragment lifecycle with respect to Activity lifecycle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004519/activity-vs-fragment-lifecycle).

Comment: Your answer is inaccurate and also the OP is already trying to set the text of the `TextView` in the way you are suggesting (read their code more closely).

Comment: @Squonk : Thanks for correcting me. Well then in that case the OP should just remove the `t.setText("weewoufzklfo")` from `onCreate()` for it to work.

Comment: What do you mean with 'YourFragmentClass'? When I create the project I only have two classes: MainActivity and NavigationDrawerFragment. Do I need to create a new class? If yes, how to make the new class called from the MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks. It works after I remove the setText inside onCreate()