# Lifecycle of hidden fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I wanted to understand the interaction between activity lifecycle and fragment lifecycle in Android, so I decided to start a new project and copy code from [this page](http://www.html.it/pag/49111/layout-adattabili-smartphonetablet-in-android/).
I then thought that to improve my comprehension it would be useful to test it on a tablet, switch its orientation and see what it happens (although maybe it was not intended for this).
Through logcat I kept track of the main events that are fired both on the activity and on the country fragment, for example in Activity Oncreate I write:

```
Log.d("TAG", "Activity: 1.onCreate");
```

This is what I get when I start from the portrait view and then rotate:

> TAG: Activity: 1.onCreate
>   TAG: Activity: 2.onStart
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 1.onAttach
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 2.onCreateView
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 3.onStart
>   TAG: Activity: 3.onResume
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 4.onResume
>   TAG: Activity: -3.onPause
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: -4.onPause
>   TAG: Activity: -2.onStop
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: -3.onStop
>   TAG: Activity: -1.onDestroy
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: -2.onDestroyView
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: -1.onDetach
>   TAG: Activity: 1.onCreate
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 1.onAttach
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 1.onAttach
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 2.onCreateView
>   TAG: Activity: 2.onStart
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 2.onCreateView
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 3.onStart
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 3.onStart
>   TAG: Activity: 3.onResume
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 4.onResume
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 4.onResume

It seems that the fragment that was added via the FragmentManager in the portrait view is still recreated after rotation, despite it was detached before. The event chain to resume it is followed again, even if it won’t be displayed.
Can you help me understand what is happening here?

**EDIT**

When I check if the fragment isInLayout()

```
Log.d("TAG", "## ContryFrag: 1.onAttach /" + isInLayout() );
```

I realize that there are two fragments after rotation: one created with the rotation and a second one who seem to be a remainder of the previous activity (which shouldn't be).

> TAG: Activity: 1.onCreate
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 1.onAttach /false
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 1.onAttach /true
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 2.onCreateView /true
>   TAG: Activity: 2.onStart
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 2.onCreateView /false
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 3.onStart /false
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 3.onStart /true
>   TAG: Activity: 3.onResume
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 4.onResume /false
>   TAG: ## ContryFrag: 4.onResume /true

**EDIT 2**

This is the dummy code I used to get onSelectedCountry(String country), which is not provided:

```
public void onSelectedCountry(String country)
{
    String[] x = {country, "city0", "city1", "city2", "city3", "city4", "city5"};
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(x);
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Here is [my code](https://github.com/giusdin/androidfragment). Sorry for the delay, it was the first time I used github.

Comment: it's maybe because of your log. Check it in your `City fragment`. In `landscape` mode, I think that `city` fragment and `country` fragment log the same things.

Comment: Do you mean that maybe the code sending messages to logcat is called by City fragment as well? No, I'veadded code only to the main actvity and country fragment.

Comment: It is better if you post some code in your post for convenience sake. The posted link does not show all the code. For example, is there code for the Activity.onStart()?

Comment: The only code that is missing is the one that provides lists of countries and cities. So I implemented my dummy getCountries() and getCitiesByCountry(country) functions. Apart from this, all the code is shown in that page and the app is perfectly working. Only if you thoroughly debug it you discover what I noticed.

Comment: You have not posted any code that shows how you are creating your fragments. Simply showing the output of log statements is not enough.  What exactly is your question? Is it "Why are there multiple Fragments being added"? If so, show the code where you create fragments.

Comment: Please read the webpage I linked in the first place. All the code is there. And yes the question is why there are two fragments attached to the activity after rotation and not only one.

Comment: Well i don't speak the language so cannot tell what the code is trying to achieve but yes, the fragment is added every time the activity starts without checking if it already exists so my answer below is a valid one for the question you have asked.

Comment: @GiuseppeDini, I think you should post your code in Github or somewhere. You can get more attention if it is easy for us to get the relevant code. At this point, everyone else is guessing what the problem is. Good luck with this project.

Comment: @The Original Android, I've posted my code. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Please check following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23004846/1406172

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you add a `Fragment` to the `FragmentManager`, it remains there until either you remove it manually or until the `Activity` permanently finishes. (Restarting an `Activity` such as what occurs when the device rotates does not cause it to Finish)

Rotating the device does not clear the Fragments. If you create a new `Fragment` and add it to the `FragmentManager` at any time in the `Activity` Lifecycle without first checking if the `Fragment` already exists in the `FragmentManager`, you will simply add a new `Fragment` every time you do anything that causes the `Activity` to be restarted.

For example, this code should only allow one copy of your fragment to be added.

```
protected void onResume() {

    String TAG = "COUNTRYFRAG";

    CountryFrag f = (CountryFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);

    if (f == null) {
        f = new CountryFrag();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(f, TAG)
                .commit();
    }

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size();
    Log.v("FRAGS", "There are " + count + "fragments in the fragment manager.");

}
```

whilst this one will add a new one every time you rotate the device.

```
protected void onResume() {

    String TAG = "COUNTRYFRAG";

        CountryFrag f = new CountryFrag();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(f, TAG)
                .commit();

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size();
    Log.v("FRAGS", "There are " + count + "fragments in the fragment manager.");

}
```

The code at the link seems to be using the presence of `savedInstanceState` to determine whether to add the Fragment or whether to return from the method. This is not reliable as you may not be saving anything in the state and therefore it could always be null. It is better to specifically check if you have already added the Fragment.

i.e

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) 
            return;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.So it seems that when the activity starts in portrait mode, it adds a CountryFragment via the fragment manager.
Then after the rotation in landscape, a new CountryFragment is added because it was required by the layout xml file.
Maybe the check about savedInstanceState is not the best way to avoid double insertion of fragments, but in this case it is not the culprit.
Despite no new fragment was added by the fragment manager we have now two CountryFragments. The strange thing is that both of them are attached, createviewed, started and resumed, even if only one is shown.

Comment: After a rotation back to portrait mode, we still have two CountryFragments: the first one and the one added after the first rotation. The condition on savedInstanceState works. Then if rotated for the second time in landscape mode, no new CountryFragments is added now. It seems that there is a built-in mechanism to preserve from double insertion of fragments from layout out resources,

Comment: I wasn't trying to fix the specific case you referenced as you stated you did not want that. My answer was an explanation of why you are seeing the behaviour you are seeing which is because multiple fragments are being added due to poor checking of whether the fragment was added previously.

Comment: Re your comment above, Both fragments are added to your container. You are only seeing one because they are identical and are placed directly on top of each other.

Comment: As I said previously, I don't understand the page you linked but there is a fragment being added by the XML. If you are also adding a fragment in code then you will end up with 2 fragments. You would normally use one method or the other but not both. XML is more restrictive aas you are limited to the fragments defined in it.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining before what than page is meant to do. It's simply a way to show how layouts can be different depending on the configuration. That's all. The experiments about rotation and fragments lifecycles are my ideas.

Comment: I also observe that if starting from lanscape mode, after rotation the activity is blank. That is maybe because as you say “XML is more restrictive as you are limited to the fragments defined in it”? That is a second Fragment is not created because of the check and the first one is not displyed because recognized as coming from XML?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't use the previous instance of your fragment.
Android persists the Fragment layout and associated back stack when an Activity is restarted due to a configuration change.
It looks like when the recreation of the Activity occurs a new fragment is created.
Try to add the following code to your Activity's onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...    

    ContryFrag fragment = (ContryFrag) mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container); 

    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new ContryFrag());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And remove the code of fragment creation.

Comment: The strange behaviour has not disapperared. Anyway my goal is not to solve a problem, but to understand the reason of what I reported. The code is available at the link I posted, it is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

The linked article has fragments defined in the layout xml. Your code in github is creating and adding fragments by code. Are you using both these together?

Comment: The code is identical. It creates and adds fragments  by code or by xml, depending on its orientation (landscape or portrait).