# how to change the Title in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I would like that the title in the menu will change by the fragment name that was click. for the code below what i get is that, the actual title in each fragment is "Home" and its does not change. but i found that when i click on an item in the menu the title changing for a second and return back to the "Home" title. i implemented the ondrawer but still i don't know what could cause that.

my code:

```
 package com.example.matant.gpsportclient;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.CreateEventFragmentController;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.DBcontroller;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.GoogleMapFragmentController;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.ManageEventFragmentController;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.ProfileFragmentController;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.InterfacesAndConstants.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.InterfacesAndConstants.Constants;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.DrawerItem;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.DrawerItemCustomAdapter;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.SessionManager;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {

    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private DBcontroller dbController;
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;
    private SessionManager sm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        sm = SessionManager.getInstance(this);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = "Home";
        DrawerItem [] drawerItems = new DrawerItem[Constants.MENU_SIZE];
        drawerItems[0] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.home,"Home");
        drawerItems[1] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.profile,"Profile");
        drawerItems[2] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.search,"Search Events");
        drawerItems[3] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.create,"Create Event");
        drawerItems[4] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.manage,"Manage Event");
        drawerItems[5] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.attending,"Attending List");
        drawerItems[6] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.recent_search_24,"Recent Searches");
        drawerItems[7] = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.logout,"Log Out");

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[0]);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            selectItem(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(String resStr) {
        try
        {
            if((this.progress!= null )&& this.progress.isShowing())
            {
                this.progress.dismiss();
            }
        }catch (final IllegalArgumentException e){
            Log.d("Dialog error",e.getMessage());
        }catch (final Exception e){
            Log.d("Dialog error",e.getMessage());
        }
            finally {
            this.progress = null;
        }

        Log.d("handleResponse", resStr);
        if(resStr!=null)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resStr);
                String flg = jsonObj.getString(Constants.TAG_FLG);
                switch (flg) {
                    case "user logged out":
                    {
                        sm.logoutUser();
                        break;
                    }
                    case "query failed": {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToDBController() {

        String user = sm.getUserDetails().get(Constants.TAG_EMAIL);
        BasicNameValuePair tagReq = new BasicNameValuePair("tag","logout");
        BasicNameValuePair userNameParam = new BasicNameValuePair("username",user);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(tagReq);
        nameValuePairList.add(userNameParam);
        dbController =  new DBcontroller(this,this);

        dbController.execute(nameValuePairList);

    }

    @Override
    public void preProcess() {
        this.progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Log Out",
                "Logging out...", true,false);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0: //Home
                fragment = new GoogleMapFragmentController();
                break;
            case 1: //Profile
                fragment = new ProfileFragmentController();
                break;
            case 2: //Search Events
                //fragment = new SearchEventFragmentController();
                break;
            case 3: //Create Events
                fragment = new CreateEventFragmentController();
                break;
            case 4: //Manage Events
                fragment = new ManageEventFragmentController();
                break;
            case 5: //Attending List
                //fragment = new AttendingListFragmentController();
                break;
            case 6: //Recent Searches
                //fragment = new RecentSearchesFragmentController();
                break;
            case 7: { //Log Out
                logout();
                finish(); //destroy the main activity
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    public void logout()
    {

        sendDataToDBController();
    }
    /*@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        logout();
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok i found the problem, your answer was good and i really change the title each time from the fragment but in addition i need to disable this line:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
```

from the onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed

Answer (score 12):

Set it for all your fragment. This should do the work!!

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.id.your_fragment_layout, container,
            false);
    getActivity().setTitle("<your title>");

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand your answer, i do not want to change all my code because everything is working i just want to change the title handler.

Comment: i use this command in the oncreate of "Create Event" but still nothing changed: getActivity().setTitle("Create Event");

Comment: onCreate and onCreateView are not the same, you may check in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004519/activity-vs-fragment-lifecycle

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not set the title to ActionBar, set the title to Activity, you can do so from the activity or fragment.
For Activity:

```
setTitle("New Title");
```

or for Fragment:

```
getActivity().setTitle("New Title");
```

Comment: i change this function as you say but steel i get the problem: "public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        this.setTitle(mTitle);
    }"

Comment: the function setTitle is already there, you can get title from your activity. no need to store mTitle there. what is your new problem?

Comment: i use it in the Create fragment but still nothing changed: getActivity().setTitle("New Title");

Answer (score 0):

add this in your fragment

```
getActivity().setTitle("title");
```

add remove this below line from Drawer activity

```
getActivity().setTitle("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it worked for me

> place a Textview inside the toolbar of app_bar activity
>
> Inside the oncreateView of a fragment put this code

```
 TextView heading;
    heading=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Id_title);
    heading.setText("your text");
```

By using this you can Name each fragments with your own text

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView()write following code:

```
activity!!.setTitle("Your Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is "Changing toolbar title according to the fragment name"
i tip to see if the "navigation graph" of the "navigation drawer" you set all stuff correctly: every fragment should have something like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_ID_OF_FRAGMENT"
    android:name="rubik_cube.navigation.ui.NAME_OF_Fragment"
    android:label="@string/TOOLBAR_TITLE_HERE"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_LAYOUT_GO_HERE" />
```

and in the resources the fragment desired title string,
in the res/layout the layout of the fragment,
in the code a class that handle the fragment stuff

and toolbar works perfectly!

if u want to change toolbar name dinamically according to other stuff like idk pressing a button, select from menu u need to change it programmatically instead with:

```
ActionBar toolbar = requireActivity().getSupportActionBar();
if(toolbar != null) toolbar.setTitle("your title");
```