# Android Fragment-Listview to open new Fragment and transfer the data

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have a Fragment that has a listview,

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerMySubjects"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSubjectLists"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to transfer the data from the listiview when selected to a new fragment. Here is my code in my onItemClick

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    InstructorFragmentSelectedSubject newFragment = new InstructorFragmentSelectedSubject();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("code", code);
    args.putString("title", title);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerMySubjects, newFragment).commit();
}
```

Here is my code in my new fragment, onCreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_instructor_selected_subject, container, false);

    tvSelectedCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedCode);
    tvSelectedTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedTitle);

    String code = getArguments().getString("code");
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");

    tvSelectedCode.setText(code);
    tvSelectedTitle.setText(title);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: OMG! i forgot to put my question LOL. Anyways. My code is not working, i cannot transfer/open a new new fragment when clicking/selecting an item in my listview. I dont know what is wrong. There is no error. But I cant open the new fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change LinearLayout to Frame Layout, and see what will happens :)
I think yout code add fragment below your listview, and it has match_parent so it is invisible for user.

Try to avoid making containers for fragment with child view. Better create new fragment with listview and than add to the container. Than replace view by clicking listitem.

//EDITED:

If you change listview to listview fragment you will need communication between fragments. In your listview click listener you should make a callback to the activity, and activity can change fragments using FragmentManager and put some values to the new fragment.

Here you can check how to add callback: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I changed the LinearLayout to FrameLayout. I can now see the newFragment. But, it overlaps with the oldFragment.

Comment: My project's main container is a SlidingTab Layout and a ViewPager. One of the Tabs(which is a fragment) is called StudentFragment. This fragment contains a listview. If I select one of the items in the listview. I want to open a newFragment that contains the information inside the selected fragment. So far, I can now see the newFragment. But, it overlaps with the StudentFragment (it didnt replace, I used transaction.replace)

Comment: It not replacing listview, because listview isn't a fragment.

Comment: You can create new ListViewFragment in StudentFragment, and than replace it. Or You can replace whole StudentFragment

Comment: it will replace the container of the listview, which is a linearlayout

Comment: Container is also not fragment. Fragment isn't View neither ViewGroup.

Comment: Hi, i get it now. I modified the newFragment.xml. Can you help me also in transferring the data I selected from the listview so that I can use/view in the newFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Fragment Life Cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) try this code.

```
private String code = null;
private String title = null;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_instructor_selected_subject, container, false);

        tvSelectedCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedCode);
        tvSelectedTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedTitle);


        tvSelectedCode.setText(code);
        tvSelectedTitle.setText(title);

        return view;
    } 

     @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (getArguments() != null) {
              code = getArguments().getString("code");
              title = getArguments().getString("title");
              }

        }
```

Comment: @Maki also read these links....https://dzone.com/articles/visualization-android-activity and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23004846/3678308